# iPhone Parsing Time From RSS Troubles

Tags: iphone, ios, calendar, rss

I seem to be having some difficulties with parsing times due to start and end of Daylight Savings Time.  The RSS feed in question has this for its items:

```
 <item>
<title><![CDATA[Men's & Ladies Bible Class Widows Luncheon]]></title>
<description><![CDATA[(Tue, 02 Apr 2013 11 am - 1 pm EST)
 ]]></description>
<pubDate>Tue, 02 Apr 2013 11:00:00 EST</pubDate>
<link>http://www.localendar.com/elsie?DAM=PublishedEvent&amp;event_id=315&amp;calendar_id=199640&amp;k=040213&amp;cb=false</link>
<guid>http://www.localendar.com/elsie?DAM=PublishedEvent&amp;event_id=315&amp;calendar_id=199640&amp;k=040213&amp;cb=false</guid>
</item>


<item>
<title><![CDATA[Wednesday Night Services]]></title>
<description><![CDATA[(Wed, 03 Apr 2013 7 pm - 8 pm EST)
 ]]></description>
<pubDate>Wed, 03 Apr 2013 19:00:00 EST</pubDate>
<link>http://www.localendar.com/elsie?DAM=PublishedEvent&amp;event_id=283&amp;calendar_id=199640&amp;k=040313&amp;cb=false</link>
<guid>http://www.localendar.com/elsie?DAM=PublishedEvent&amp;event_id=283&amp;calendar_id=199640&amp;k=040313&amp;cb=false</guid>
</item>
```

In my app, the detailTextLabel displays the date and time.  Here is the code for the rows of the table.

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
    }

    RSSEntryCalendar *entry = [_allEntries objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    NSDateFormatter * dateFormatter = [[[NSDateFormatter alloc] init] autorelease];
    [dateFormatter setTimeStyle:NSDateFormatterMediumStyle];
    [dateFormatter setDateStyle:NSDateFormatterMediumStyle];
    [dateFormatter setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone timeZoneWithName:@"America/New_York"]];
    NSString *articleDateString = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:entry.articleDate];


    cell.textLabel.text = entry.articleTitle;        
    cell.detailTextLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ - %@", articleDateString, entry.blogTitle];

    return cell;
}
```

The location for all events is the Eastern Time Zone, which is why I have that as the set time zone.  This ensures everything shows Eastern Time, and not simply whatever that equals in their time zone.

The issue is that while the two entries I posted as examples show 11 and 7 for times in the pubDate category, the app writes it as 12 and 8.

Any thoughts on how this could be fixed?  Should some setting be made on the calendar itself, or am I doing something wrong in the app?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe set the format explicity?

`[dateFormatter setFormat:@"EEE, d MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss zzz"];`

Comment: That only sets up the way it shows the date.  Found out the issue is because the localendar.com service we use sets everything as EST even when it is EDT, so therefore, the iPhone auto adjusts and adds an hour when DST is in effect.